# How can I call every instantiated function of a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, template-meta-programming

Is it somehow possible to call every instantiation of a template function without knowing what will get instantiated at write-code-time?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print_size_of()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(T) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    print_size_of<int>();
    print_size_of<double>();

//won't work but maybe it shows what i want to do:
    template<typename T>
    print_size_of<T>();
//is there a syntax so that the compiler replaces that with `print_size_of<int>(); print_size_of<double>();`
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Why not just wrap `print_size_of<int>()` and `print_size_of<double>()` in a `print_size_of_types()` function?

Comment: "won't work but maybe it shows what i want to do" - no, it doesn't show.

Comment: @EdgarRokjān I think he wants to run the function for any `T` (in this case `int` and `double`) that has been given to the template. If he had an additional `print_size_of<string>();`, he would want to print all 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible; you need to add some static variable inside the function template body to record those instantiations.

In the code below, every instantiated function will have a static variable, whose constructor will register the function pointer to a global registration center:

```
std::vector<void(*)()> funcs;

struct helper {
    explicit helper(void (*f)()) { funcs.push_back(f); }
};

template<typename T>
void print_size_of()
{
    static helper _(&print_size_of<T>);
    std::cout << sizeof(T) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    print_size_of<int>();
    print_size_of<double>();

    std::cout << "All instantiation:\n";

    for ( auto f : funcs ) {
        f();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is not strictly recording instantiation. It only records those being called before. If you instantiate it by other methods like taking its address:

```
void (*f)() = &print_size_of<short>;
```

but don't call it, then this function pointer won't be registered.

**EDIT2:**

In fact, it is possible to faithfully record all instantiations. The key point is to associate the instantiation of the function template to the instantiation of a class template. Then a static member of that class will be guaranteed to initialize before entering `main()` function.

```
// this one is to make sure `funcs` is initialized
auto &get_funcs() {
    static std::vector<void(*)()> funcs;
    return funcs;
}

template<void (*f)()>
struct helper {
    helper() { get_funcs().push_back(f); }
    // this is a static class member, whose initialization is before main()
    static helper _ins;
};

template<void (*f)()> helper<f> helper<f>::_ins;

template<typename T>
void print_size_of()
{
    // force instantiation of a class
    const void *_ = &helper<&print_size_of<T>>::_ins;
    std::cout << sizeof(T) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    print_size_of<int>();
    print_size_of<double>();

    void (*f)() = &print_size_of<short>;

    std::cout << "All instantiation:\n";

    for ( auto f : get_funcs() ) {
        f();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you fail to take into account static initialization order. It may nearly look like a solution, but it just fails on the last inches.

Comment: @Deduplicator For those of us less versed in template black-magic, can you explain?

Comment: Note that this will only register the function when it's invoked for the first time.

Comment: @liliscent: Angew spelled it out for you.

Comment: @Deduplicator I would never have understood that's what you meant from the comment.

Comment: If you wrap the template function in a `struct` and make your registration object a `static` member of that struct, it could register it without having to call the function. Though you'll need to make sure the list of instances is initialized before your `static` member, such as by returning a `static` local variable from a function.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Maybe this is also possible. I also came up with a similar approach. In fact, the key point is to associate a class template instantiation to the function template instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible.

You can get close by calling every instantiation which was already called once (Use a static variable to register on first call), but that's the best you can do.

Comment: Upvoted, because I couldn't find a way to completely remedy my solution. However, I really doubt there is **no** solution for this question. Perhaps your conclusion is not solid enough.

Comment: In case you are still interested in, I think I have managed to give a complete solution. See my updated answer. If possible, please tell me if there are still flaws in my current approach.